# facebook xid doesn't work

Tags: facebook, comments

i need separate comment thread for each post on my website, so i followed instructions at http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472, ie i inserted the code:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
 <fb:comments href="www.mysite.com" xid="postPOST_ID_HERE"></fb:comments>
```

under each post.

but it doesn't work and there is SAME comments thread under each post.

if i try this code:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
 <fb:comments href="http://www.mysite.com/news.php?id=POST_ID_HERE"></fb:comments>
```

it seems to work, ie i get separate comment thread per post. but according to facebook instructions href parameter needs to be canonical url. am i doing something wrong in the first case or is the second example way to go (even if against facebook manual)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use both the href and the xid variables. I think the href variable is the newer version according to [Facebook Developer Blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472?ref=notif&notif_t=open_graph_comment) this is the new code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments href="YOUR_CANONICAL_URL"></fb:comments>
```

It also says "If you already have the original Comments Box installed, include the parameter migrated="1" to keep existing comments" and shows this as an example:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments xid="YOUR_XID" migrated="1"></fb:comments>
```

I am using the first version I posted here, but using addresses like you mentioned, and it works. So I'd say go with the second version even if it goes slightly against what they say. It works properly for me.

Comment: what's YOUR_XID, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plugin doesn't work on my 2 sites on different servers from yesterday, but on http://www.vesti.ru/doc.html?id=442871 plugin works normally