# Facebook Comment Box - Change Domain

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

*First, Sorry for my English - I'm from Austria.*

Hy guys!

I made a website, and before the launch of the website, i add the comment box ([Link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)) with the url from the developer server.

Now, the website is online, and many people has posted with their Facebook Accounts on the new  page, before i realize, that i has forgot changing the URL at the relaunch.

**My Question: Is it possible, to change the domain (from dev.example1.com, to example2.com), and keep the existing comments?**

I dont find any solutions on google and co, so i hope someone can help me!

*(Fur sure its not possible to say the peoble, they should post the same things again :))*

Thanks! Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those comments are stored in facebook's database and they are associated with your application's XID rather than your domain. So, those comments will still exist even after changing the domain name

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557175/facebook-xid-doesnt-work) question, it might help you solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your Answer.
I tested it, but the Comments ar gone :(

Are there some parameters, what i have forgot?

(Here is the Website, with the CommentBox: [HardDance](http://www.harddance.at/index.php?page=newsdetails&id=56))

Comment: Did you mention the `XID` for your application?

Comment: I have set the meta tag for the Application-ID.
(<meta property="fb:app_id" content="277860492266821"/>)

Comment: Oh, and i have forget to say:
I changed the Domain-Name in the Application to the new one.
But it doesn't work.

Comment: You can change domain name multiple times as long as you have common `XID`

Comment: Oh, ok, and without this XID there is no way to keep the older Comments? The XID i have to set in the fb-comments div tag, right?
xid="events_53", for example? Or in the data-href URL, like data-href="http://www.harddance.at/... url .. ?xid=events_53" .. Sorry, but i am a Facebook Developer - "Newbie"

Comment: Yep, without `XID` there is no way to retain your comments